# Integral with two different answers using real and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

The integral is$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dθ}{2-\cosθ}.$$Just to skip time, the answer of the indefinite integral is  $\dfrac2{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt3\tan\left(\dfracθ2\right)\right)$.

Evaluating it from $0$ to $ 2 \pi$ yields$$\frac2{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3 \tanπ)-\frac2{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3 \tan0)=0-0=0.$$But using complex analysis, the integral is transformed into$$2i\int_C\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2-4z+1}=2i\int_C\frac{\mathrm dz}{(z-2+\sqrt3)(z-2-\sqrt3)},$$
where $C$ is the boundary of the circle $|z|=1$. Then by Cauchy's integral formula, since $z=2-\sqrt3$ is inside the domain of the region bounded by $C$, then:
$$2i\int_C\frac{\mathrm dz}{(z-2+\sqrt3)(z-2-\sqrt3)}=2πi\frac{2i}{2-\sqrt3-2-\sqrt3}=2πi\frac{2i}{-2\sqrt3}=\frac{2π}{\sqrt3}.$$

Using real analysis I get $0$, using complex analysis I get $\dfrac{2π}{\sqrt3}$. What is wrong?

Comment: OK, so I only spotted this after I already knew what the answer was, but nonetheless: notice that the integrand is always strictly positive, so the integral can't possibly be 0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with the real approach is that you make the change of variable $t=\tan\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$ for $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$.

This is problematic since your substitution need to be defined and continuous for all $\theta$, but you have a problem when $\theta=\pi$.

**Edit:** Note that if you split the integral into $\int_0^\pi+\int_\pi^{2 \pi}$, you are going to get the right answer, as for one integral you are going to get $\arctan(- \infty)$ and for the other $\arctan(+\infty)$:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}θ}{2-\cos \theta}=\int_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d}θ}{2-\cos \theta}+\int_\pi ^{2 \pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}θ}{2-\cos \theta}\\
= \lim_{r \to \pi_-} \int_0^r \frac{\mathrm{d}θ}{2-\cos \theta}+ \lim_{w \to \pi_+} \int_w^{2 \pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}θ}{2-\cos \theta}\\= \lim_{r \to \pi_-} \left(\frac{2\tan^-1( \sqrt{3} \tan( \frac{ r}{2}))}{ \sqrt{3}}-0\right)+ \lim_{w \to \pi_+}\left(0- \frac{2\tan^-1( \sqrt{3} \tan( \frac{ r}{2}))}{ \sqrt{3}}\right).$$

Comment: Oh I see, so I have to solve it without this substitution? Or could I keep this substitution and change something else?

Comment: @khaled014z See the edit. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Brilliant, that was kind of a tricky substitution, thank you

Comment: When this is next edited, you want tan^{-1} twice in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Note that that tangent function, $\tan(x)$, is discontinuous when $x=\pi/2+n\pi$.  So, the antiderivative $\frac2{\sqrt{3}} \arctan\left(\sqrt 3 \tan(\theta/2)\right)$ is not valid over the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Instead, we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta=2\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{2-\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta=\frac{4}{\sqrt3}\left.\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt 3 \tan(\theta/2)\right)\right)\right|_0^\pi=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: Don't you mean $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$?

Comment: Hi Mark ! **Happy New Year !**

Comment: @DavidG Yes, of course.   Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi Claude!  Happy New Year to you too!